# Is it possible to pass the Parent instance to a Child compontent into props attributes?

Tags: reactjs

I am passing the whole Parent instance to the Child in the props like this:

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
  render() {
      return <Child parent={this} />;
  },
doAThing() {
    console.log("Doing A Thing!");
  }
});

var Child = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.onClick}>Do A Thing...</button>
  },

  onClick() {
    let parent = this.props.parent
    parent.doAThing();
  }
});
```

It works fine, i just wonder if is good practice or if i should avoid it.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a good practice because a child shouldn't be aware of parent's implementation, according to [the principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege). When a child is supposed to do something, it should be provided with a callback:

```
<Child onClick={() => this.doAThing()} />;
```

And it can use a prop directly:

```
<button onClick={this.props.onClick}>
```

Comment: Yes, i was wondering how to manage this when there is a list of tasks that a child component should perform that are defined in the parent.
THANK YOU!